# QFormLayout: Label column truncated on resize

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

When I resize my **QFormLayout**, the label column disappears.

Here is my layout:

[image: Form description]

```
label = QLabel("I don't want to be truncated!")

horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()
for i in range(5):
    button = QPushButton(str(i))
    horizontal_layout.addWidget(button)

form_layout = QFormLayout()
form_layout.addRow(label, horizontal_layout)
```

On resize:

[image: Label gone]

Why is that column hidden? There should be enough place to display it, because the buttons width can be very small. Here is their minimum size:

[image: Minimum size]

In my true program, the label column is **truncated**. I tried to reproduce the problem, but I failed. However, a disappearing column is almost the same problem.

Full source code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QFormLayout, QHBoxLayout,\
    QPushButton, QLabel


class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        label = QLabel("I don't want to be truncated!")

        horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for i in range(5):
            button = QPushButton(str(i))
            horizontal_layout.addWidget(button)

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow(label, horizontal_layout)
        self.setLayout(form_layout)

        self.setMinimumWidth(1)

application = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
application.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if  this line

```
self.setMinimumWidth(1)
```

is replaced by

```
button.setMinimumWidth(1)
```

as second line in the for loop it works